# 2.79 works for me- 2.81a refuse to start - cmd screen only flashes

Tags: error, windows, startup-file

I have been using 2.79 works well. installed both 2.8 and even 2.81a on a Dell xps8300 W7.When I tried to start it , the cmd-screen only flashed. blender did not start. Doe's anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: Start it from the [command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/workflows/command_line.html) for more information on why it's failing.

Comment: If your XPS 8300 has a Radeon HD 5770 as GPU, then it does not meet the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x. For AMD GPUs [GCN first generation architecture or later is required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview).